# What is going on with Drupal Packagist?

Tags: 7, composer

I was using

```
  "repositories": {
   "drupal": {
       "type": "composer",
       "url": "https://packagist.drupal-composer.org/"
   }
  },
```

in my composer.json file, but now it started saying that it can't load it and it is deprecated so go to https://www.drupal.org/node/2822344 instead. However, the info on there suggests changing it to point to https://packages.drupal.org/7 but this also doesn't seem to exist.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: https://medium.com/@dcorbacho/packagist-drupal-composer-has-been-shut-down-9a6c47b9eaa4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://packages.drupal.org/7 is the correct url, its just that drupal.org does not server any content under this url. Composer will call https://packages.drupal.org/7/packages.json

Answer (score 2):

packagist.drupal-composer has been shut down

https://medium.com/@dcorbacho/packagist-drupal-composer-has-been-shut-down-9a6c47b9eaa4#.ylaxgo3n9

You must use the official Package Repository from Drupal.org, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-packagesdrupalorg

for Drupal 7 use https://packages.drupal.org/7

for Drupal 8 use https://packages.drupal.org/8

Comment: according to my comment :D

Comment: But with more relevant info.